# Does Sneak Attack count power attack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

The wiki said "Sneak attacks do not "combine" with power attacks: you will only get the sneak bonus. (Otherwise, you would get an 18x damage modifier, which is enough to kill just about anything in the game instantly.)"

Does it mean I don't need to press longer to make the slashing harder because it is meaningless? Should I press the button once quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Press the button once, quickly.  Holding the button to slash harder is meaningless.